# Ubuntu 20.04 FireFox Cannot connect to server. I have Wi-Fi connectivity

Tags: networking, firefox, internet

OS:       Ubuntu 20.04
Wi-Fi:    MEDIALINK Wireless-N USB 2.0 Adapter
-Connected; all networks visible
Browser:  FireFox
-Opens normally; Hmm. We're having trouble finding that site.
We can't connect to the server at "you name it".
Ubuntu 20.04 is a fresh install independent of any other OS.
I ran NetworkManager and there are ten(10) warnings highlighted.

- interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
- error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
- sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: p2p cancel failed   etc...

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: i read "man journalctl". please explain what it is you want me to do?